# python flask create <div> for each directory

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

How do I create a div for each directory using flask?

I tried this but it does not do anything and theres nothing in the console:

python file:

```
    # Get a list of directories in the 'servers' directory
    folders = [d for d in os.listdir('servers/') if os.path.isdir(d)]

    # Create a div element for each folder
    divs = []
    for folder in folders:
        div = f"<div class='list'><a href='/servers/{folder}'>{folder}</a></div>"
        divs.append(div)

    # Join the div elements into a single string
    divs_string = "\n".join(divs)

    # Render the template and pass the div elements as a variable
    return render_template('home.html')
```

html file (home.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/home.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/CrystalVortex/Feather-CSS/9318334ceedfa61d6a64349a558ef1e48ef19cb2/Feather1.7.css">
    <title>FeatherPanel | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/create" method="post">
    <button class="btn_blue">Create Server</button>
    </form>
    {% for directory in directories %}
        <div>{{ directory }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `listdir` function just returns a list of filenames. To test within your loop whether it is a directory, the `isdir` function expects the path including the folder name.

You can then pass the returned list to the template.
I'm using `locals()` here to pass all local variables to the template. However, you can also pass the variables individually with a key.

```py
@app.route('/servers/')
def servers():
    # Get a list of directories in the 'servers' directory
    folders = [d for d in os.listdir('servers') if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('servers', d))]

    # Render the template and pass the div elements as a variable
    return render_template('home.html', **locals())
```

Within the template you can iterate over said list to create a "div" element for each entry.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/home.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/CrystalVortex/Feather-CSS/9318334ceedfa61d6a64349a558ef1e48ef19cb2/Feather1.7.css">
    <title>FeatherPanel | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/create" method="post">
        <button class="btn_blue">Create Server</button>
    </form>

    {% for folder in folders %}
        <div>{{ folder }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

You didn't describe what should happen when a user clicks a link for a listed directory. Keep in mind that only files in the static folder are accessible from the client. If you want to use an anchor to refer to listed directories outside of the static folder, you need another endpoint.

Comment: thanks! I thought there wasn't any way to do this.